# As3 Actionscript drawing within the outlines

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, drawing

I am developing a coloring game using adobe air and as3. I have an image with black outline and the user can draw / color the image using a pen tool. I need help to figure out how can I restrict the user to draw within the outlines only. Masking the image with the line-graphics is something I have tried but it hangs the application. Any hint / suggestion towards the solution is appreciated.

following is the code on mouse_down event

```
_dot = new MovieClip();
_dot.graphics.lineStyle(lineSize, color);
_dot.graphics.moveTo(img.mouseX,img.mouseY);
img.addChild(_dot);
```

Comment: Does your target image contain a megaton of segments which need to get colored separately? If yes, split them before you place them to stage, then just allow one segment at a time to get painted, use its alpha mask to determine area that can be painted.

Comment: @ReriseStudios Why not respond to others? If still not solved, you need to define your meaning of _"...Restrict the user to draw **within the outlines only**"_. For example if you have image of a white background the outline is two circles overlapping (one in front is full circle, other one is obscured) then what is your expected result... does "restrict" mean any white space (except black outlines) can be coloured? Or it means only one circle segment can be coloured? Or it means ignore white and only colour the black outline part (thus keeping it _"within the outlines"_ themselves)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say, the area you are drawing on is a **DisplayObject** with an instance name of **Canvas**. What you need is to check if the mouse is on **Canvas** or not.

In order to do so, you want to use the [DisplayObject.hitTestPoint(...)](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint()) method with the **shapeFlag** set to **true** (if it is **false**, it tests the point against the object's rectangle bounding box, which would produce the wrong results for any non-rectangular or rotated shapes).

So, you do as following:

```
var P:Point = new Point;

// First, convert coordinates to Stage coordinates,
// because the method requires so.
P.x = Canvas.mouseX;
P.y = Canvas.mouseY;
P = Canvas.localToGlobal(P);

// Now, test if the mouse is within the given canvas.
if (Canvas.hitTestPoint(P.x, P.y, true))
{
    // The drawing should happen here.
}
```